# How can open a shapefile using R maptools package?

Tags: shapefile, r, maptools

```
library(maptools)
mn.map.shp = readShapeSpatial("minnesota.shp")
```

Results this error at second line:

```
Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file
```

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: How to solve the problem the my code ini R. I want to open shape file but the result is (Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file)

Comment: From where come `"minessota.shp"`? Can you open it with another application ?

Comment: "Wall of code" questions fare poorly here (and in the other SE domains as well).  Please **edit** the question to provide a plain text description of what you are doing, what your data sources are, and what your specific problem is (including any errors, as text, in the question).  You should also specify where the error occurs, and reduce your code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to aid in debugging.

Comment: Did you set your working directory to the location of the shapefile? If not then R has no idea as to the location of the file. You can also provide a path in the function eg.,  readShapeSpatial("C:/mydata/minnesota.shp")

Answer (score 2):

Per @Jeffrey Evans advice, should set your working directory and then use proper relative path to your shapefile. Like:

```
setwd("C:/Users/R")
library(maptools)
mn.map.shp = readShapeSpatial("./folder1/folder2/minnesota.shp")
```

However `readOGR` is always prefered than `maptools` because the maptools functions neither read nor write projection information:

```
library(rgdal)
mn.map.shp<- readOGR(dsn = "./folder1/folder2", layer = "minnesota.shp")
```

Comment: I'm preferring to use the `shapefile` function in the `raster` package these days - reads the projection and you only have to specify the path of the .shp instead of the dsn/layer approach of readOGR. This means you can `file.choose()` on Windows and browse to it.

Comment: @syukri adnan sangadji , you're welcome. Please mark as answer per [tour](http://www.gis.stackexchange.com/tour)